# How can I modify a Symbol in Ruby without a RuntimeError: Can't modify frozen Symbol?

Tags: ruby, runtime-error, symbols

I am attempting to change the color of the chess piece if the position matches given criteria however keep getting the following error message:

```
Position#move_str
Failure/Error: it {expect(Position[P: [e2, e3], p:[d3, d4]].move_str(e2,d3)).to eq "ed3"}

RuntimeError:
can't modify frozen Symbol
 # ./chess.rb:24:in `color'
 # ./chess.rb:122:in `block in move_str'
 # ./chess.rb:122:in `select!'
 # ./chess.rb:122:in `move_str'
 # ./chess_spec.rb:75:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am calling the code from a separate file (which has linked properly as previous tests with other sections are working). It is running through the following code snippets

chess_spec.rb File:

```
75. it {expect(Position[P: e2, p:d3].move_str(e2,d3)).to eq "ed"}
76. it {expect(Position[P: [e2, e3], p:[d3, d4]].move_str(e2,d3)).to eq "ed3"}
```

chess.rb File color

```
21. class Symbol
22. def color
23. return @color unless @color.nil?
24. @color = :a < self ? :black : :white
25.
26. end
```

chess.rb File move_str

```
113. def move_str(from, to)
114.   piece = board[from]
115.   piece_str = piece.pawn? ? "" : piece
116.   list = find(piece, to)
117.   is_capture = board[to] || piece.pawn? && to == ep
118.   if piece.pawn? && is_capture then
119.
120.     possible_pawn_pos = [*0..7].select{|row|board[from%10+(row+2)*10] == piece}
121.     possible_pawn_pos.select! { |row| target = board[to%10 + (row+2+white(-1, 1))*10]; target && target.color != piece.color }
122.       if possible_pawn_pos == 1 then"#{from.to_sq[0]}#{to.to_sq[0]}"
123.       else
124.       "#{from.to_sq[0]}#{to.to_sq}"
125.        end
126.        else
127.            if list.size == 1 then
128.                "#{piece_str}#{to.to_sq}"
129.                elsif list.select { |idx| idx%10 == from%10}.size == 1
130.                    "#{piece_str}#{from.to_sq[0]}#{to.to_sq}"
131.                elsif list.select { |idx| idx/10 == from/10}.size == 1
132.                    "#{piece_str}#{from.to_sq[1]}#{to.to_sq}"
133.                else
134.                    "#{piece_str}#{from.to_sq}#{to.to_sq}"
135.                end
136.    end
137. end
```

chess.rb File white

```
109. def white(w,b,t=turn)
110.    t == :white ? w : b
111. end
```

I know the error is coming from line 122 as stated in the error message, and believe it is coming from the `(row+2+white(-1, 1))*10]` section, although not really that sure as am new to Ruby. As it is a Symbol I know you can not `dup` it at all. 
How then would I be able to change the Symbols color?

Thanks for any help in advance and sorry if I have made any mistakes in posting this as I am new to both Ruby and stack overflow.

Comment: Isn't it the whole point of using Symbols in Ruby that Symbols are immutable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby instances of *Symbol* are intended for use as constants or immutable value. For this reason symbols are always frozen.

```
:a.frozen? #=> true
```

The [`Object#freeze` documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-freeze) says the following about frozen objects:

> ### freeze → obj
>
> Prevents further modifications to *obj*. A `RuntimeError` will be raised if modification is attempted. There is no way to unfreeze a frozen object. See also `Object#frozen?`.
>
> This method returns self.
>
> ```
> a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
> a.freeze
> a << "z"
> ```
>
> *produces:*
>
> ```
> prog.rb:3:in `<<': can't modify frozen Array (FrozenError)
>  from prog.rb:3
> ```
>
> Objects of the following classes are always frozen: [Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html), [Float](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Float.html), [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Symbol.html).

This means that the error will be raised on the following line:

```
class Symbol
  def color
    return @color unless @color.nil?
    @color = :a < self ? :black : :white
    #      ^ Instance variable can only be read, writing to it
    #        counts as modification, thus raising an exception.
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense about where the error is coming from.

Comment: You can however change the contents of the *color* method to just `:a < self ? :black : :white`. As long as you don't save state you're good to go.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Thanks for the help